# What is the purpose of @TestConfiguration on a top-level class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot 1.4 has brought [many good improvements](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) for testing.

I am unclear of the purpose of [`@TestConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.html). It doesn't seem to work as expected.

I thought that if I use `@TestConfiguration` on a top-level class under `/src/test/java` that it gets picked up by a `@SpringBootTest` test ([see here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-excluding-config)). But this seems not to be the case. If I instead use `@Configuration` then it gets correctly picked up.

Did I misunderstand? Is the manual wrong? Is there a bug in the Spring Boot code?

Comment: There are tests that rely on its [use on a top-level class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/ExampleTestConfig.java) so it should work. Can you share an example of it not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I've asked this question, the wording in the documentation has been clarified and explains the behaviour much better now.

Per [the new documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.excluding-configuration):

> When placed on a top-level class, `@TestConfiguration` indicates that classes in `src/test/java` should not be picked up by scanning. You can then import that class explicitly where it is required, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```java
> @SpringBootTest
> @Import(MyTestsConfiguration.class)
> class MyTests {
>
>     @Test
>     void exampleTest() {
>         // ...
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

whenever we have used `<context:component-scan base-package="some.package" />` or `@ComponentScan` . it scans all . for that to prevent Spring Boot provides `@TestComponent` so that they should not be picked up by scanning.